# Office365 Outlook Profile Picture Cache Problem

Tags: outlook, office365

Does anyone know how to clear the Contact picture cache? We have issues in our company where sometimes people see old photos in Outlook. I was testing out some ideas and changed the contact picture for an employee to a different picture in my local client. Sure enough in Outlook it shows his contact photo instead of his Exchange photo. I deleted the contact card, and the wrong photo is still there. I created a new contact for him with an empty picture and still the old photo is there. I even added a new picture, and it still shows the old one in Outlook even though his contact card shows the new one!

I'm guessing this is some kind of local cache thing. I've tried going to "%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Offline Address Books" and deleting the Offline Address Books, but it says the files are in use so it won't delete.

Any ideas on what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the SecureTemp folder or the Temp Internet files. Empty your internet cache (IE's Optios). Paste the following line in the address bar of windows explorer then press enter. Securetemp is a folder under this path -  delte the folders and restart outlook.

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook
```

[Outlook SecureTemp Files Folder](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/securetemp-files-folder/)

For more information, please refer to this link:

[How Do I Clear Image Cache? - Outlook 2007 - Cached Image from incoming HTML message won't reload when new message is received w/ same image filename](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-clear-image-cache-outlook-2007-cached/7f4f4134-828c-4fea-8a45-3ef110867bb6)

Comment: I deleted everything in the Content.Outlook folder but still nothing changed with the picture. I took a look in the folder and it looks like there were a couple of pics in there, but not profile pics. I also cleared IE's cache but no change there either.